# How to limit record creation on multiple objects

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on the requirement where I have to setup the limit on number of records created on 10 custom objects.

So I have created one object called Limit__c which contains available_limit__c and required_limit__c fields.

Suppose there is an object Demo1 for which available limit is 5 records and if user try to create more than 5 records then it throws error message.

Same need to be done for all 10 objects.

I know this can be achieved by trigger on that object.

But do I need to write separate trigger for each object or there's any thing through which I need to write one trigger
and can controll all the objects.

I have Limit__c object from where I can get the available limit for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object requires its own trigger. That's how the system works. But you can, with some careful effort, make a polymorphic utility class that can handle all of the various types. The triggers would look something like:

```
trigger checkLimitsForObjectX on ObjectX (before insert) {
  LimitChecker.checkFor(Trigger.new);
}
```

The class itself would use dynamic queries, etc:

```
public class LimitChecker {
  public static void checkFor(SObject[] records) {
    String query = 'select id from '+records.getSObjectType()+' where ...';
    SObject[] results = Database.query(query);
    // figure out if we need to add errors
  }
}
```

Since you've not provided more specific details (e.g. time limit, etc), this is about the best I can offer you right now. You'll want to read more about [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) for specifics.

Comment: My aim is simple instead of writing separate triggers I want it to achieve dynamically. for example: I want user won't be able to create more than 5 records on Account,Contact,Opportunity, case objects.

Comment: @AshutoshTripathi again, triggers need to be deployed per object. You can make a common utility class, but there would still be one trigger per object for this.